# Bertrand's postulate to show $\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{n+m}\notin\mathbb Z$ for all positive integers $n$ and $m$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

This is question is from Section 3.2 Q29 from *Elementary Number Theory, and its Applications, sixth edition*.

The answer in the back of the book is

> Because $\frac{1}1$ is an integer, we may assume $n > 1$. First suppose that $m < n$. Then $\frac1n + \frac1{n + 1} + \cdots+\frac1{n+m} \leq \frac1n + \frac1{n + 1} + \cdots+\frac1{2n-1} <\frac1n + \frac1{n } + \cdots+\frac1{n} <n (\frac1n) = 1$ so the sum can not be an integer. Now suppose $m > n$. Then by Bertrand's postulate, there is a prime $p$ such that $n < p <n + m$. Let $p$ be the largest such prime. Then $n + m < 2p$; otherwise, there would be a prime $q$ with $p<q<2p\leq n+m$, contradicting the choice of $p$. Suppose that $\frac1n + \frac1{n + 1} + \cdots+\frac1p+\cdots+\frac1{n+m}=a$ where $a$ is an integer. Note that $p$ occurs as a factor in only one denominator, because $2p > n + m$. Let $Q = \prod_{j=n}^{n+m}j$, and let $Q_i= \frac Qi$, for $i = n, n + 1,\dots,n + m$. If we multiply the equation by $Q$, we get $Q_n+Q_{n-1}+\cdots+Q_p+\cdots+Q_{n+m}$. Note that every term on both sides of the equation is divisible by $p$ except for $Q_p$. If we solve the equation for $Q_p$ and factor a $p$ out of the other side, we have an equation of the form $Q_p = pN$ where $N$ is some integer. But this implies that $p$ divides $Q_p$, a contradiction.

And the mentioned Bertrand's postulate is that

> For every positive integer $n$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n$.

My main confusion regarding this proof is this part:

> Now suppose $m>n$. Let $p$ be the largest such prime. Then $n + m < 2p$; otherwise, there would be a prime $q$ with $p<q<2p\leq n+m$, contradicting the choice of $p$.

I'm trying to understand why this implies that $2p>n+m$ since from my understanding $m$ could be very large, and much larger than $n$.

One way I thought of, which makes sense to me but I want to be sure is the same form of reasoning is, and it has one glaring error I noted:

From Bertrand's postulate, we know that there exists a prime p such that $n=\frac{n+n}2\leq\lfloor\frac{n+m}2\rfloor<p<n+m$.

Taking $\lfloor\frac{n+m}2\rfloor<p<n+m$:

1. If $n+m$ even, then $\lfloor\frac{n+m}2\rfloor=\frac{n+m}2<p<n+m$ implies $2\cdot\frac{n+m}2<2p<2(n+m)$ getting our desired $n+m<2p$.
2. If $n+m$ odd, then $\lfloor\frac{n+m}2\rfloor<p<n+m$ implies $2\cdot\lfloor\frac{n+m}2\rfloor= \boldsymbol{n+m-1<2p<2(n+m)}$ **meaning it is possible that $\boldsymbol{2p= n+m}$ which is not exactly what we want**.

Past this attempt, I do not know how to get the result that was shown in the solution. The rest of the proof makes sense (when blindingly assuming that our choice of $p$ is such that $2p>n+m$), including why it is needed that $2p>n+m$ so that it cannot be a factor of any of the other denominators.

Just an explanation of why the largest choice of $p$ in $n<p<n+m$ is such that $2p>n+m$ what what I am missing in understanding.

Comment: Closest I know are things like there is a prime between n and 1.5 n or one between 0.75 n and n.

Comment: Doesn't Bertrand's postulate show there's a prime between $p$ and $2p$, hence larger than $p$?  That contradiction seems explicitly mentioned in the argument.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes... ugh this seems to be exactly what I was missing. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian's comment I realized:

Since $p$ prime is the largest prime that satisfies $n<p<n+m$, it must be that $2p>n+m$ because otherwise, by Bertrand's postulate, we know that there exists a $q$ prime where $p<q<2p$ and since $2p<n+m$ then $p<q<2p<n+m$ which is a contradiction to our largest choice of $p$ prime.

Basically all that I was missing was the reapplication of Bertrand's postulate saying that there exists $q$ prime between $p<q<2p$ leading to the contradiction only if $2p<n+m$.